# How exactly does the "and not" operation in python works

Tags: python, boolean-expression

i am trying to learn python and for that i am watching a course, in which the core concepts of the language are being taught.

I wrote the following code, in which a secret word has to be guessed:

[image]

I dont quite understand how the "and not" in line 7 works. In line 5 we define "out_of_guesses" as false, which is correct, because we didn`t started the game yet and therefore we still have guesses left. When we use "and not out_of_guesses" in line 5 we want to stay inside the while loop, as long as we are not out of guesses. But we defined out_of_guesses as False so when we negate it in line 5 it should be True, so we are out of guesses.

I am pretty sure that i am misunderstanding something so i would really appreaciate it, if someone would help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post images of code. Make your code easy to reproduce. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for explanation. Please edit your post by replacing the image with the text formatted as code.

Answer (score 1):

> so when we negate it in line 5 it should be True, so we are out of guesses

Not exactly. The `not` operator doesn't change the value of `out_of_guesses`, it instead returns the opposite of `out_of_guesses`.

Like mathematics, `x+1` does not change the value of `x`, it simply evaluates to one more than `x`.

And the game loop can only run when two conditions are true:

- The secret word has not been guessed.
- The player still has guesses.

The second condition is expressed as `not out_of_guesses`.

Remember that the while conditions must evaluate to `True` for the loop to run again.